# Lazy loading routes in react router v6

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, async-components

I'm trying to lazy load route elements with the `createBrowserRouter` function in React Router v6 but I keep getting this error: `Matched leaf route at location "/admin/reports/enrollees" does not have an element or Component. This means it will render an  with a null value by default resulting in an "empty" page.
This is my routes file:

```js
export default createBrowserRouter([
    {
        path: '/admin/reports',
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                element: <Index />,
            },
            {
                path: 'enrollees',
                lazy: () => import('../../components/Reports/Enrollees'),
            },
            {
                path: 'facilities',
                lazy: () => import('../../components/Reports/Facilities'),
            }
        ],
    }
])
```

I tried doing this at first:

```js
export default createBrowserRouter([
    {
        path: '/admin/reports',
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                element: <Index />,
            },
            {
                path: 'enrollees',
                element: lazy(() => import('../../components/Reports/Enrollees')),
            },
            {
                path: 'facilities',
                element: lazy(() => import('../../components/Reports/Facilities')),
            }
        ],
    }
])
```

But I got the error: `Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.`

Comment: The code doesn't *look* incorrect, and appears to match the official lazy loading [example](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/dev/examples/lazy-loading-router-provider/src/App.tsx). What version of `react-router-dom` do you have installed? Please [edit] and share your `package.json` file, and also run `npm list react-router-dom` in the terminal in the root project directory to log what is actually installed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was facing the same issue, i resolved it this way

```
{
  path: "dashboard",
  lazy: async () => {let { Dashboard } = await import("./pages/Dashboard")
    return { Component: Dashboard }},  
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This strange problem had been bothering me for a few hours, but I finally figured out the problem

First make sure your component's name is `Component`, then use named export instead of default export

eg. YourComponent.jsx

```
export function Component(){
  return <div>something</div>
}
```

the route object

```
{
  path: 'your-component',
  lazy: () => import('./YourComponent'),
}
```

If you want to keep your component name and also use default export, you can do

eg. YourComponent.jsx

```
export default function YourComponent(){
  return <div>something</div>
}
```

the route object

```
{
  path: 'your-component',
  async lazy() {
    let YourComponent = await import("./YourComponent");
    return { Component: YourComponent.default };
  },
}
```

Comment: You don't necessarily need to rename your component to `Component`...which would make managing the code across many components difficult.  Instead, you would add (typically to the end of the component's file) `export const Component = MyOriginalComponent;` and `Component.displayName = 'MyOriginalComponent';`.  This lets you keep your code in a function that has meaning and that matches its filename, while exporting it in a way that makes React Router happy.