# Lazy-load React route configuration

Tags: reactjs, micro-frontend

I have an application using microfrontend architecture, that needs to share routing. I want to use React as a host. I want to let the microfronted to add their own routes.

I know [`react-router`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main) has the ability to [lazy-load components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76340518/lazy-loading-routes-in-react-router-v6). `loadComponent` is similar in Angular. My question is how to lazy load route configrations.

I know I can add a route for match everything ([splat/`*`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/route#splats)) and then implement a new router with my own configuration, but that is overkill.

In Angular [`loadChildren`](https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules) property helps to load children route configuration. In the newer versions even arrays, not just router modules with `forChild`. Is there anything similar in React?